# what does this code snippet do?

Tags: python

can somebody give me an explanation about the following code?

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic

class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, user):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.getUser(user)+"\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class FingerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = FingerProtocol

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # whats is ** ??
        self.users = kwargs

    def getUser(self, user):
        return self.users.get(user, "No such user")

reactor.listenTCP(1079, FingerFactory(moshez='Happy and well'))  
# explain call to fnger factory??
```

Comment: From the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It's [keyword argument notation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The call to FingerFactory (a strange name, BTW) is instantiating a FingerFactory object. The parameters to that call are passed to the `__init__` function of the class, where they are accepted by the `**kwargs` parameter as a dictionary:

```
{'moshez': 'Happy and well'}
```

So this is assigned to the `users` attribute of the new FingerFactory instance.

Answer (score 0):

And the other question, regarding `FingerFactory` call.

That's how you do instantiation in Python. You don't use a `new` keyword. You just call the class as though it were a function. The constructor of the class is `__init__`